# COPY de postgresql mediante Laravel es posible?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Estoy intentando importar archivos grandes en Laravel usando Postgresql (Sentencia COPY). Pero me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con DB::raw y DB::select pero no me sale, alguna ayuda por favor, llevo horas atascado en este problema.

Ya le di permisos al proyecto y nada.

Cuando lo valido desde el motor de base de datos, funciona con normalidad.

OJO: El aplicativo lo tengo en mi local y la base de datos esta un servidor.

Muchas Gracias de antemano

Comment: COPY espera que el archivo esté en una ruta local al servidor PGSQL. Se lo tendrías que poner localmente al servidor en alguna parte y darle ESA ruta.

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente ese fue mi gran error, debia guardar el archivo en el servidor.

Comment: Súper! Te lo puse como respuesta para que otros con la misma pregunta sepan cuál es la respuesta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COPY espera que el archivo esté en una ruta local al servidor PGSQL. Se lo tendrías que poner localmente al servidor en alguna parte y darle ESA ruta.

Entonces, puedes poner un SFTP en el servidor donde está PGSQL y enviarle el archivo, usar SCP, etc. Luego puedes darle la instrucción COPY usando una ruta local al servidor donde está PGSQL y él leerá el archivo :)